# Angular2 Using Subscribes as promises

Tags: angular

I am not sure how to do a very simple Angular2 using subscribers :

```
a() {
  return getValueFromService() // Return Observable
  .subscribe(callA)
}

b() {
  a().subscribe(callB) // This won't work as a() return a Subscriber
}
```

Basically, I want to be sure that my callB will always come after my callA.
It's like having `a()` returning a `Promise` and using `then()` on it.

I am using the very latest Angular2 beta version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the `do` operator:

```
a() {
  return getValueFromService() // Return Observable
    .do(callA)
}

b() {
  a().subscribe(callB) // This won't work as a() return a Subscriber
}
```

The `subscribe` method doesn't return an observable but a subscription... The `do` operator return a new observable, so you can subscribe on it. It must be used in the case when you want to trigger something but don't handle the result (the result won't be propagated in the asynchronous data flow).

Another option would be to leverage the `flatMap` operator if you want to get the result of `getValueFromService` within the subscribe callback:

```
a() {
  return getValueFromService() // Return Observable
    .flatMap(callA)
}

b() {
  a().subscribe(callB) // This won't work as a() return a Subscriber
}
```

In this case, `callA` must return an observable.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
a() {
  return getValueFromService() // Return Observable
  .toPromise().then(callA);
}

b() {
  a().toPromise().then(callB); // This won't work as a() return a Subscriber
}
```

then call it like

```
a().then(b);
```

Comment: I believe Observables are the new standard now, and I would like to avoid using Promise. I am not sure in what version of Angular2 you are now, but toPromise() doesn't exist on Observable on mine.

Comment: `toPromise` is an operator and like each operator it needs to be imported like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';`. There is some hype about observables and they have some advantages. `Promise` is still valid though. If you prefer `Observable` then Thierrys answer should fit your need.

Comment: My bad, indeed I forgot to add the operator. Thanks for your contribution in here sir.